# How to check if type implements ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

How can I check if a given type is an implementation of `ICollection<T>`?

For instance, let's say we have the following variable:

```
ICollection<object> list = new List<object>();
Type listType = list.GetType();
```

Is there a way to identify if `listType` is a generic `ICollection<>`?

I have tried the following, but with no luck:

```
if(typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(listType))
       // ...

if(typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(listType))
      // ...
```

Of course, I can do the following:

```
if(typeof(ICollection<object>).IsAssignableFrom(listType))
     // ...
```

But that will only work for `ICollection<object>` types. If I have an `ICollection<string>` it will fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
bool implements = 
    listType.GetInterfaces()
    .Any(x =>
        x.IsGenericType &&
        x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (ICollection<>));
```

Comment: Note that a type can implement several `ICollection<>` interfaces with different generic types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this code, it works for all collection type

```
    public static class GenericClassifier
    {
        public static bool IsICollection(Type type)
        {
            return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsGenericCollectionType);
        }

        public static bool IsIEnumerable(Type type)
        {
            return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsGenericEnumerableType);
        }

        public static bool IsIList(Type type)
        {
            return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsListCollectionType);
        }

        static bool IsGenericCollectionType(Type type)
        {
            return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(ICollection<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        }

        static bool IsGenericEnumerableType(Type type)
        {
            return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(IEnumerable<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        }

        static bool IsListCollectionType(Type type)
        {
            return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(IList) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        }
    }
```